# Possible to hook into Media Library preview File column and use a custom image?

Tags: functions, filters, hooks, uploads, media-library

The project I'm working on, I couldn't find an easy way to have WordPress create the thumbnails sizes I needed without tons of waste, nor to simultaneously generate WebP versions, so I disabled the thumbnails, I upload a full-size jpg or png, and then I manually generate my WebP and other sizes and copy them to the uploads. A custom PHP function handles building responsive `<picture>`.

However, I'd like to avoid the media library loading up the full-size image as the thumbnail all the time, as it's a waste of bandwidth. I'd like to point to a small WebP or JPG version that is not in the library but in the uploads folder and have it load that image instead. The file name is almost the same, just needs to be appended with `_width` (width being a number) which I could do with `strtr` or something.

Is there a way to access the Media Library File column with a function and a hook/filter so I can change the src path to the thumbnail image? I'd also need to avoid `PDF`, `SVG` and `TXT` file uploads and just target `JPG` or `PNG` files. If it's not possible, I'll have to generate a thumbnail with a custom size.

[image]

Comment: WP 5.8 can create webp images automatically if the server has support. Otherwise, it's not clear what you mean by file column, can you describe it using other words or a screenshot? Are you talking about the custom table view? Or the panel on the right when selecting an image? Or something else?

Comment: Also, have you asked how to dynamically generate images to avoid the waste you didn't want? This sounds more like a  fix for a fix rather than a fix for a problem

Comment: I couldn't find anything about dynamically creating all file formats necessary. WordPress seems to default to using whatever type you feed it (give it WebP, you only get WebP, etc.) I built Photoshop actions and have a file renamer, so it's actually not much of a chore, time is limited and couldn't spend more time digging or posting for solution. As for "File Column," thumbnails are displayed in the File column in the Media Library. I want to modify the wp_get_attachment_image src for the thumbnails. `wp_enqueue_media` might be the way, but not sure how to go about it. I'll add a screenshot.

Comment: Also, as I said, WordPress makes thumbnails for everything, even if you don't need the sizes for all images in your design. I scoured this site and others and even posted here (or SO) about how to specifically make WordPress use the `image_size`s I wanted based on a file prefix, but no one responded. As it is, I already have 2,000 images do to responsive and the site isn't live, and I couldn't keep waiting without a reply, so this is the route I took. Everything works great and I use a plugin to organize uploads into directories. Just need to modify the admin thumbnail src somehow.

Comment: And one last note, having WordPress dynamically generate WebP might not be ideal. I have to finesse quality in Photoshop sometimes and I made variants of my actions because sometimes the image quality will fall apart unless you bump up the WebP quality by a few percent, while other images hold up fine. Having one quality setting for everything wouldn't work well for this project.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_media` is not the solution, and check the documentation/release udpates for WordPress 5.8 announcing webp support, they mention filters and technical details. Also be mindful that a non-trivial portion of the web is unable to display webp images still, support is widespread but not for everybody

Comment: I'd also note that excess upload folder size due to the extra file for each image size is usually only an issue if you upload tens of thousands of items while skimping on disk space. Even then, CDNs such as Jetpacks Photon make it a non-issue by serving both webp and non-webp depending on the browser, and doing it on the fly. It also looks like you're discounting proposals based on hidden criteria you're not sharing, as long as they remain hidden you'll get suggestions that aren't usable and nobody will know that until you respond.

Comment: That's why I'm using responsive images with `source` and `srceset` and `img`, so there are WebP with JPG or PNG fallbacks for browsers that don't support it and I'm lazy loading them as well. Also, I will have tens of thousands of images which is less than if I let WordPress generate thumbnails I don't need. I'm almost at 10,000 images now. At any rate, all I need to know is how to hook into the Media Library thumbnail previews so I can edit the src path.

Comment: when I say skimping on diskspace I mean spinning up the cheapest hosting with <2GB of available space then filling it with as many 50MP images as possible. These days it's difficult to get a VPS or hosted solution with such a small drive. the smallest VPS digital ocean offer is a 25GB SSD for $5pm

Comment: I have a managed VPS with LiquidWeb, with enough room, but I don't like having excess files regardless. No reason to clutter up things unnecessarily. I'm also trying to avoid the errors that can occur when individual server folders have too many files and there are problems listing the files through FTP and otherwise (which Ive read about on here and other forums). Plus, with this many files, having them organized into subdirectories is much easier to manage and find things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this after being pointed in the right direction. In my case, I filtered `wp_get_attachment_image_attributes` to change all the paths in the admin for attachments at once.

In my case, I am using descriptive suffixes on all my image files (i.e. `_featured` etc) so modifying them was easy using `strtr` which I also used to change the extension from jpg to webp.

Now all attachment image previews load in the files I want in the correct format at the desired size, and it works for Media Library, featured images, and custom fields.

```php
add_filter( 'wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_attachment_filter', 10, 3 );
function my_attachment_filter($attr, $attachment, $size){
    if (is_admin()){
        if (array_key_exists( 'src' , $attr)){
            $old_src = $attr['src'];
            $new_src = strtr($old_src, array('_featured' => '_featured_eighth', '_portrait' => '_portrait_204', '_og.' => '_og_320.', '.jpg' => '.webp'));
            $attr['src'] = $new_src;
        }
    }
    return $attr;
}
```